# Find the angle of rotation and minor axis length of ellipse from major axis length, center, and two points?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'd like to describe the ellipse centered at the origin with a fixed major axis length of $2a$ that passes through two points $(u_x, u_y)$ and $(v_x, v_y)$ (both within $a$ of the origin). In particular, I need to compute the angle of rotation $\phi$ of this ellipse, and the length $2b$ of its minor axis.

I tried the straightforward approach of just setting up a couple of equations to solve for the coordinates of the foci $(f_x, f_y)$ and $(-f_x, -f_y)$:

$\sqrt{(u_x - f_x)^2 + (u_y - f_y)^2} + \sqrt{(u_x + f_x)^2 + (u_y + f_y)^2} = 2a = \sqrt{(v_x - f_x)^2 + (v_y - f_y)^2} + \sqrt{(v_x + f_x)^2 + (v_y + f_y)^2}$

If I were able to use these equations to determine $(f_x, f_y)$ then presumably $\phi = \arctan(f_y / f_x)$ and $b = \sqrt{a^2 - f_x^2 - f_y^2}$...but solving those equations for $(f_x, f_y)$ is beyond my algebraic skills. (They also appear to flummox the SymPy solver.)

Comment: Interesting problem. From playing around with it a bit in GeoGebra, it looks like there are generally two such ellipses.

Comment: I doubt that there’s going to be any “nice” algebraic solution to this, and certainly not a nice general formula. Instead of trying to compute the foci, I would look at the family of conics parameterized by $\theta$ centered at the origin that pass through the two points and $a(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. The equations for these are easily constructed with a determinant. [De la Hire’s construction of an ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#de_La_Hire's_point_construction) seems promising, too: you can construct two inner circles and try to find the angle at which they coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=mx$ be the equation of the major axis of the ellipse, and $b$ its semi-minor axis (which lies on line $y=-x/m$). Distances $u_a$ and $u_b$ from point $u$ to the lines of the axes are given by:
$$
u_a^2={(u_y-mu_x)^2\over1+m^2},\quad
u_b^2={(mu_y+u_x)^2\over1+m^2},
$$
and analogous expressions can be written for point $v$. If $u$, $v$ belong to the ellipse, then: 
$$
{u_b^2\over a^2}+{u_a^2\over b^2}=1
\quad\text{and}\quad
{v_b^2\over a^2}+{v_a^2\over b^2}=1.
$$
This is a system of equations for the unknowns $m$ and $b$: I solved it with Mathematica and, apart from the trivial solutions $(b=a,\ m=\pm i)$, it has two real solutions:
$$
{1\over b^2}=
\frac{
u_x^2+u_y^2+v_x^2+v_y^2
-a\left(2u_x^2v_x^2+2u_y^2v_y^2+2 u_x u_y v_x v_y+u_y^2 v_x^2+u_x^2 v_y^2\right)
\pm 2 (u_xv_x+u_yv_y)\sqrt{\Delta}}
{(u_y v_x-u_x v_y)^2}
$$
$$
m=
\frac{
-u_x u_y \left(a\left(v_x^2+v_y^2\right)-1\right)
+v_x v_y\left(a\left(u_x^2+u_y^2\right)-1\right)
\mp(u_y v_x-u_x v_y)\sqrt{\Delta}}
{u_x^2 \left(1-a v_y^2\right)+v_x^2 \left(a u_y^2-1\right)},
$$
where: $\Delta={\left(1-a \left(u_x^2+u_y^2\right)\right) 
\left(1-a\left(v_x^2+v_y^2\right)\right)}$.

Comment: This is terrific! (SymPy appears to choke on these equations as well, which may be more an indication of my inexperience with computer algebra systems than a symptom of SymPy's shortcomings.)

I wrote a very quick and dirty Python script to [visualise](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D50lOp7W4AUKeX0.jpg:large) the results: https://gist.github.com/7066d2de2afb0bf3c87812499ed4d540